# Cruise Control .NET, .NET 4.0, WS 2008 R2, NUnit seems to require COMPLUS_Version?

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net, windows-server-2008-r2, .net-4.0

Trying to configure NUnit 2.5.8.10295 in Cruise Control.NET on Windows Server 2008 R2, .NET 4.0, my NUnit task times out, and nunit-agent.exe seems stuck running.  It works fine from the command line.

The only solution I've found is to define the environment variable COMPLUS_Version.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

C:\builds\nunit\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console-x86.exe
    C:\builds\testLogs
    C:\builds\build\NUnit.Tests\bin\Debug\NUnit.Tests.dll /nologo /framework=4.0.30319
    10 
    0,1,3,5
    
        
            COMPLUS_Version
            v4.0.30319

I tried various edits to nunit-console-x86.config, but nothing worked but this awkward looking "solution".

Thanks

Comment: What version of CruiseControl.NET are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely running into the known bug reported here https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/602761 Your setup is identical to our setup as posted (comment 1). Your fix is the one suggested by the project maintainer. The other option is to not use the nunit-agent and force nunit console to run as .NET 4.0

Comment: As an amendment to this answer, here is the app.config guide:

1. Open each app.config file in the text editor of your choice (we did nunit.exe, nunit-x86.exe, nunit-console.exe nunit-console-x86.exe)
2. Right below the configuration append the following:
  <startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
  </startup>
3. Save the file and restart Nunit

Note that this will force nunit to run with the .net framework v4.0.30319 all the time, for us this isn't a big deal as we have separate build environment for each version of the .net framework on which we deploy against.